# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage warning when using react-native-html-to-pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

When I submit app on app store I am getting following warning:

> following notification form the app-store connect: ITMS-90809:
>   Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of new
>   apps that use UIWebView APIs starting from April 2020.

I tried implementing solution from following link:
https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf/issues/151#issuecomment-569597226

After implementing this solution warning from app-store goes but I am getting these two issues:

1. Images from local cache are not shown in PDF
2. Font from local cache are not shown in PDF

Also, I am not facing above issues on simulator. I tried running build in release mode and on various versions of simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840722/5954472

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to load images from local cache into PDF.
So I have tried following workaround.

1. Converted images into base64 using **react-native-image-base64**
2. Loaded those base64 images into pdf

As I was facing this issue only with IOS, I wrote platform specific code for IOS only.

**Please note:**

> Converting image to base64 can be heavy operation. If anyone have any
>   solution. Please suggest.