# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage when i use react-native-webview

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

i'm using react-native-webview but when i publish the app to Testflight it send me :

App Store Connect

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "AlBiddaPark" 1.2.19 (37). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Best regards,

The App Store Team

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I dont use React Native, isn't there a newer version that uses WKWebView instead?

Answer (score 8):

1- Run in root folder screen command `grep -r UIWebView node_modules/* t`

2- Check dependencies which need updated, excluding:

node_modules/react-native

node_modules/metro

node_modules/fbjs

Update all external dependencies

4- Replace all WebView what used default react native. Replace it on https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

5- Added script into **Podfile**

```
post_install do |installer|
 # REMOVE ALL WEB VIEWS
 react_project = Xcodeproj::Project.open("../node_modules/react- 
 native/React/React.xcodeproj")
 react_project.main_group["React/Views"].files.each do |file|

    if file.path.match(/^RCTWebView/)
       file.remove_from_project
    end

  end
  react_project.save
 end
```

6- Run **pod install** command, and you are done

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue recently and here are the reasons I found and how I fixed it.

**Reason -** This issue occurs in two cases :-

1. You are using old version of `react-native-webview` and it uses `UIWebview` which is no longer accepted by Apple Appstore.

**Fix -** Update the `react-native-webview` dependency. Refer [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)

2. One of the package used by you in the app uses `UIWebView` instead of `WKWebview`.

**Fix -** You have to check which package uses the UIWebview.
Use command `grep -r "UIWebview" node_modules/*` to search for uses in node_modules
Use command `grep -r "UIWebview" ios/` to search for uses in ios folder (This will show the Pods which are using old versions, ignore the mentions in the comments).

Now, you just have to update the versions of Pods or the packages in packages.json. In my case, I was using `react-native-firebase` v5 which was using old pods so I updated version to 5.6.0 and Pods to following versions :-

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth',  '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'AppAuth','~> 1.3.1'
```

So, in a nutshell, you just have to remove use of `UIWebview` and replace with `WKWebView` everywhere in your app.

Comment: My problem was the same as yours, with `react-native-firebase` v5. I put the same pod versions and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

WKWebView is now supported by React Native 0.57 and Expo SDK 31
Check [here](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/wkwebview-support) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try to find all including Pods folder `UIWebview`, make sure there's no file calling it and update those calling version accordingly.

For me the dependency was `react-native-device-info`.
[image]

Comment: It really helped me find the packages causing the issue.